# Constructing dynamic lists of lists with Polymer

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use Polymer and am struggling to figure out how to create my system in a Polymer-y way.

I'd like a left nav bar (a column on the left side), [as shown in the example app docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up). For the purposes of the explanation, the left nav bar shows a list of people and the main content window shows a list of books they own. When a person is selected, the main content window should be updated to show only that person's books.

Both lists should be dynamically populated via a network query and be able to be re-populated via a refresh button. It seems like this might complicate how I bind data, as the functions can't just live in a the shadowdom, as the nav bar and content lists need to be able to communicate.

From the day I've spent looking into Polymer, the nav bar (list of people) seems a natural candidate for `<iron-selector>`. The list of books sounds like `<iron-list>`. I'll need to have several instances of the book list, however--one for each person.

Should I create a `<book-list>` custom element for this, perhaps with `<iron-list>` in the template? Is it straightforward to create these `<book-list>` elements in response to selections made in `<iron-selector>`, as I won't know how to create them before querying for book owners? Any pointers on how to do this?

This sounds like a very basic use case, but I still don't know enough about Polymer to have any intuitions about the best way to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about maybe using a router? You could dynamically create your menu in the bar with the usernames. When a username is clicked, the tool navigates to `/user/<USER_ID>`. You then have an element in your main view that then requests the user with the `USER_ID` and then can output the books associated with that user. Similar to how the [shop demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/case-study) works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this working. As a starting point, I leaned heavily on the [example given in the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up) that uses the [app-drawer-template](https://github.com/Polymer/app-drawer-template).

As suggested by a commenter above, using a router ended up being part of the answer. What was confusing me was that I wan't sure how to dynamically update both the `<iron-selector>` used in that example as well as the `<iron-pages>`. I wanted both to represent the same list of users. How would I keep these in sync, etc?

I ended up with three custom elements. Two were thin wrappers around `<iron-selector>` and `<iron-pages>`. The third was a `<user-provider>` element. The role of `<user-provider>` is to perform the request for the list of users and expose the result as a variable that the other two elements can interact with.

`<user-provider>` has only a refresh button. It has a property called `users` of type `Array`. In the `ready()` lifecycle callback and in response to clicking the refresh button, it updates the list of users. Note that `reflectToAttribute` and `notify` are both set to true, ensuring that it can indeed provide the list to the other elements. A stripped down version is shown below:

```
<dom-module id="user-provider">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    </style>
    <paper-fab icon="refresh" on-tap="refresh"></paper-fab>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'user-provider',
      properties: {
        users: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        }
      },
      refresh: function() {
        this.refreshUsers();
      },
      refreshUsers: function() {
        var _this = this;
        // in reality I require a browserify module here
        window.getUsersViaPromise()
          .then(retrievedUsers => {
            _this.users = retrievedUsers;
          });
      },
      // Element Lifecycle
      ready: function() {
        this.users = [];
        this.refreshUsers();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

My `<user-selector>` element takes an array as an argument. The thing that was stumping me here was that I didn't realize how simple it was to use a `dom-repeat` template inside of an `<iron-selector>`. I thought I'd have to wrap the repeats in a `<div>` or something, at which point the `<iron-selector>` would stop working. With `dom-repeat` I'm able to even use my special `settings` element and keep it always at the bottom of the list. The `incoming` variable corresponds to the element that is selected.

```
<dom-module id="user-selector">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        --app-primary-color: #4285f4;
        --app-secondary-color: black;
      }
    </style>

    <iron-selector
      selected="{{incoming}}" 
      attr-for-selected="name" 
      class="drawer-list" 
      role="navigation">

      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{users}}">
        <a name="view{{index}}">{{item.instanceName}}</a>
      </template>

      <a name="settings">Settings</a>

    </iron-selector>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'user-selector',
      properties: {
        incoming: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          notify: true
        },
        users: {
          type: Array,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        },
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

`<user-pages>` is a thin wrapper around `<iron-pages>`. It works together with `<user-selector>` to update the content displayed in the main portion of the app.

```
<dom-module id="user-pages">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>

    <iron-pages role="main" selected="{{incoming}}" attr-for-selected="name">

      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{users}}">
        <user-summary
          name="view{{index}}" 
          username="{{item.userName}}">
        </user-summary>
      </template>

      <settings-view name="settings"></settings-view>

    </iron-pages>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'user-pages',

      properties: {
        users: Array,
        incoming: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          notify: true
        },
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And, finally, my `<my-app>` element plumbs it all together.

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        --app-primary-color: #4285f4;
        --app-secondary-color: black;
      }

      app-header {
        background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
        color: #fff;
      }
      app-header paper-icon-button {
        --paper-icon-button-ink-color: white;
      }

      .drawer-list {
        margin: 0 20px;
      }
      .drawer-list a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 16px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: var(--app-secondary-color);
      }
      .drawer-list a.iron-selected {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .drawer-list a.subroute {
        padding-left: 32px;
      }
    </style>

    <app-route
        route="{{page}}"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>

      <!-- Drawer content -->
      <app-drawer>
        <app-toolbar>My App</app-toolbar>
        <start-app-button></start-app-button>
        <user-provider users="{{retrievedUsers}}"></user-provider>
        <user-selector incoming="{{page}}" users="{{retrievedUsers}}">
        </user-selector>
      </app-drawer>

      <!-- Main content -->
      <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

        <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div title>My App</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

        <user-pages
          incoming="{{page}}" 
          users="{{retrievedUsers}}">
        </user-pages>

      </app-header-layout>

    </app-drawer-layout>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',
      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        },

      },
      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)'
      ],
      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Note in particular the way that `<user-provider>` is responsible for obtaining the list of users and exposing it just via a variable, allowing the other two elements to make obtain the data via basic databinding. That, along with the `dom-repeat` elements as immediate children of `<iron-selector>` and `<iron-pages>`, allowed this to be pretty straight forward once I started thinking of it in the Polymer way.